# In the case that adverbs don’t modify verbs

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

For example, ‘I run happily.’ I notice that doesn’t mean running is happy, but I run, being happy. However why is it called ‘verb modifier’? Do I misunderstand adverbs?

Comment: ***Happily*** describes the ***way*** in which something is done (***running***, in this case). You *could* use an adjective to modify the noun (***me***, in this case), as in ***Happy, I ran home***. Some may think that doesn't *quite* mean the same thing as ***I ran home happily***, but bearing in mind we can also use the "flat adverb" form ***I ran home happy***, I'm not convinced it's worth trying to draw semantric distinctions between them. It's just different ***syntax***.

Comment: "Happily" modifies "run". It's a manner adjunct expressing how you run.

Comment: In "I ran home happy"', "happy" also modifies "run" but it refers to the subject and hence is predicative (it's called a predicative adjunct). Semantically, though, there's little real difference.

Comment: @BillJ You mean happy just modifies subject but happily can be used for someone else’ happiness?

Comment: I don't think @BillJ actually *meant* to say that, but it's true that ***He** ran home, happily* is in principle "ambiguous" in that "happily" could be relative to the subject (him) ***or*** the speaker / writer. A distinction which doesn't *really* exist if the subject ***is*** the speaker anyway! :)

Comment: @alicea no, as I said, in "I ran home happy", "happy" is a modifier in the verb phrase, but it's an adjective phrase referring to the subject and hence is called a predicative adunct. Note that you can say "I was happy" but not "I was "happily".

Comment: "Happily" certainly can be regarded as modifying "run".  However, in response to the OP's question "Why is it called verb modifier? Do I misunderstand adverbs?", the answer is surely "yes, you do".  The names of the parts of speech are ancient, are loose translations from Greek to Latin, and aren't to be taken too literally.  Adverbs don't always modify verbs.  Sometimes they modify other things.

Comment: Yes, they can modify adjectives, deterninatives, other adverbs,  prepositions etc.,  and even nouns and noun phrases.